# Should I do retouching on Photoshop before color grading on Lightroom or vice versa?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, workflow, retouching

Is there a difference if I do skin retouching for portrait or fashion photography for an image in Photoshop first and then do the color correction and color grading in Lightroom? Should I do that first and then bring the image into Photoshop, or simply it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always do the color grading stuff before, because if done after retouching it can make the editing more visible. The edited parts are always a bit different from their surroundings and will react differently to the color tools.